# Road/Lane Data - Routing v7

Tags: routes, here-api

We are looking for a way to get road data along a route. For instance, we want to know how many lanes are on the road/maneuver and if it's one-way, two-way, or divided highway.

Is it possible to get this data for each maneuver on the route?

Answer (score 0):

The route V7 API doesn't return exactly whether the road is one way or two way etc.

The link attributes in V7 provides the following information explained in the below link:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-param-type-route-representation-options.html#type-route-attribute

Additionally, you can use this tool to check the available parameters returned for the request:
https://refclient.ext.here.com/#url=https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?routeattributes=sh,gr&mode=balanced;car&consumptionmodel=default&maneuverattributes=po,ti,pt,ac,di,fj,ix&language=en-us&jsonattributes=41&metricsystem=metric&waypoint0=geo!stopOver!52.564637,13.309205&waypoint1=geo!stopOver!52.425845,13.521379&app_code=4A04BJZiGAavKm867wcH8A&app_id=dHclbe4kurhteO3thGPl

Screenshot for your reference:
[image]

However, you can fetch some additional information from the PDE layer "LANE_FCn" which provides information like:

```
Lane driving direction.
```

Values:
B : BOTH DIRECTIONS
F : FROM REFERENCE NODE
N : CLOSED IN BOTH DIRECTIONS
T : TO REFERENCE NODE

The details explained here: https://tcs.ext.here.com/pde/layer?region=EEU&release=21120&url_root=pde.api.here.com&layer=LANE_FC1

However, to get this data you have to make an additional requests to the layer.
For example:
https://pde.api.here.com/1/tiles.json?layers=TRUCK_SPEED_LIMITS_FC1&level=9&tilexy=547,420&app_id=&app_code=&meta=1&callback=onLoadPDETiles&Ref

You can check fleet telematic documentation for more information.
You can also make the above request with apiKey by changing the endpoint to fleet.ls.hereapi.com.